# WP App - Use SkyDrive without user logging in

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive

Is it possible for a WP application to access the user's SkyDrive files and folders without prompting them to log in to SkyDrive and grant access? If so, how do you get the session? I don't see why a user who is already logged into the phone needs to log in again when they can grant access when the app installs.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such an option - you need to sign in at least one time - after that it's possible to remember login and password.
I'm not only sure if it's possible to see files which are set public without signing in.